# Compress Image topic with h264 streaming for low bandwidth connection?

Tags: opencv, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I faced the problem that sending the video with big resolution (1920x1080) is very difficult even with image transport. The raw or compressed images are too bit for sending over the network (WiFi) and the theora also can't handle such resolution (fps is too low).

Maybe someone was working with sending big image and can help me where can I find or how can I implement for example h264 streaming. Or maybe there are additional plugins for image_transport?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379644/compress-image-topic-with-h264-streaming-for-low-bandwidth-connection?/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2021-06-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used it myself, but you could see whether [daniilidis-group/ffmpeg_image_transport](https://github.com/daniilidis-group/ffmpeg_image_transport) can help. It's an FFMPEG based `image_transport` plugin, which supports any format supported by FFMPEG (including `h264` and `h265`). HW accelerated encoding/decoding is also supported (such as `nvenc` fi).

There are other `image_transport` plugins which purport to do a similar thing, but they all look rather old/stale:

- [tilk/h264_image_transport](https://github.com/tilk/h264_image_transport) (more recent / up-to-date fork: [yoshito-n-students/codec_image_transport](https://github.com/yoshito-n-students/codec_image_transport))
- [orchidproject/x264_image_transport](https://github.com/orchidproject/x264_image_transport) (more recent Clearpath fork: [clearpathrobotics/x264_image_transport](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/x264_image_transport))

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2021-06-05**:
Thank you for your help, I have tried ffmpeg_image_transport and it seems to work. However, the encoding isn't to much in the first look, it is probably needs some configuration adjustments. So I will try.

Thank you!!!